# Comparing new-timspan totalhours .... not functioning as expected

Tags: powershell, compare

I am trying to compare two dates and decide based on the number of hours gap but the comparison doesn't seem to work. I tried to cast `TotalHours` to `[int]` but no luck. What it surprises me is that I get the same result using `-gt` or `-lt`.... :?

it must be something simple but I dont see it.

here the  code

```
$stamp = "14/11/2015 14:20:57"
$rightNow = Get-Date  
$stampDateTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($stamp,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
$difference = NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $stampDateTime –End $rightNow
if ([int]$difference.TotalHours -gt 24 ) {  $ok = "OK"  }   
  if ($ok){
   Write-Host "VALID"
}else{
   Write-Host "BAD"
}
```

Comment: Are you setting `$ok` somewhere else in the script first? If so, that is probably causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  `if ($ok)` is the issue. All strings when evaluated as booleans will return true.

Changing it so that you are using boolean would be one way to address it.

```
if ([int]$difference.TotalHours -gt 24 ) {  $ok = $true  }   
  if ($ok){
   Write-Host "VALID"
}else{
   Write-Host "BAD"
}
```

You should also set a known value at the beginning of the script to use as a flag. This is important as the variable state will persist between executions in a PowerShell session.

```
# assume false
$ok = $false
```

Depending on your needs you don't need to keep this logic. You can bypass the second `if` all together because as presented it is redundant.

```
if ([int]$difference.TotalHours -gt 24 ) {
   Write-Host "VALID"
}else{
   Write-Host "BAD"
}
```

I understand this might just be the simple example you used to make the question.

---

Consider the following to understand what happened. Any non-zero length string will resolve to $true when cast as a boolean.

```
PS C:\> [boolean]"OK"
True

PS C:\> [boolean]"VeryBad"
True

PS C:\> [boolean]""
False
```

Comment: Writing `$ok = [int]$difference.TotalHours -gt 24` is a bit more succinct and it makes sure that $ok has a value whether or not the timespan is > 24. If $ok is set in a higher numbered scope, then it will get picked up and used in your if statement, if the timespan is <= 24.

Comment: @user2460798 This is true. There are __many__ ways of doing things. As long as you understand there can be no wrong answer really. As shown the code is cleaner if you simply omit the `$ok` logic altogether.

Comment: The important point was that the $ok variable is uninitialized through one code path.